# How to get download speed in KB/sec?

Tags: java, android, download, randomaccessfile

I'm trying to read data from `InputStream` and write it into sdcard by using `RandomAccessFile`. I want to implement *download speed*. So I think, by get the writing speed from `RandomAccessFile` is the best way to implement that. Here's my code:

```
long downloaded = 0;
status = DOWNLOADING; 
URL url = new URL(requestUrl);

try {
    String extStorage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
    String file = extStorage+"/abc.zip";

    RandomAccessFile output = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");

    System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");

    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setReadTimeout(5000);
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    connection.connect();

    long fileLength = connection.getContentLength();
    InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

    while (status == DOWNLOADING) {
        byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];

        // Read from server into buffer.
        int read = stream.read(buffer);
        if (read == -1)
            break;

        // Write buffer to file. I need to get this writing speed.
        output.write(buffer, 0, read);
        downloaded += read;
    }
    output.close();
    stream.close();
}
```

How do I get the writing speed from `RandomAccessFile` in KB/sec?

*Or, have you any idea?*

Thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a rough one from doming something similar to this:
Start a little `runnable` that gets called every second.
Inside your class have

```
private static int bytesWritten = 0;
private static int kbPerSec = 0;
```

Inside the `runnable` have something like

```
kbPerSec = bytesWritten / 1000;
bytesWritten = 0;
//Do with the result what you want
```

Alter your while loop slightly

```
kbPerSec = 0;
bytesWritten = 0;
//Start runnable
while (status == DOWNLOADING) {
    byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];

    // Read from server into buffer.
    int read = stream.read(buffer);
    if (read == -1)
        break;

    // Write buffer to file. I need to get this writing speed.
    output.write(buffer, 0, read);
    //Keep track of how much has been written since the last time the runnable was called
    bytesWritten += read;
    downloaded += read;
}
//Stop runnable
```

Comment: I placed that loop inside the `Runnable` as you answered, but it doesn't work.

Comment: its display how much data you downloaded not show you downlaod speed.